# Reload startup file without restart?

Tags: interface, startup-file

Is there a way to reload the startup.blend file without restarting Blender or reloading the default file? I tried using the general application template, but this forces me to save the current scene and reopen it. I'm looking for a way to do this all while inside blender.

Say I mess something up on my UI Layout and want to revert back to my standard startup.blend for its layout, but without having to open a new file or restart blender, or by going outside blender to copy over the startup.blend in the directory

[image]

Comment: In the *Preferences > Load & Save* you can disable *[X] Load UI* and it will keep your current UI when you open a blend file. The original startup.blend is in Blender's installation directory. There are actually four of them (should be five? One for each File > New > ... entry?) When you save the startup file it's located in your user home file where Blender stores the preferences. For windows it's C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\<version>\config

Comment: Thank you @Blunder, I'm aware of the Load & Save disable Load UI, that can also be done when opening files if I'm not mistaken, or correct, turned off altogether in Prefs. That's not the only way the UI can get messed up however. The AppData roaming only works for full installation no? Not Blender builds

Comment: Yes, I've just wanted to mention the Load UI option. It might be helpful - or not. But you can restore the original startup.blend and make a backup of your customized startup.blend for sure. This works not only for full installations but also for the portable/ZIP versions of Blender.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file.

Then, your Startup File will be reloaded.